# Should questions whether "it's ok to use the latest version of X yet" be closed?

Tags: discussion, support

This question

[Using PHP version 5.2 or 5.3 for commercial products?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143327/using-php-version-5-2-or-5-3-for-commercial-products)

seems to me to be the sort of thing that should be discouraged, because it will have no value in a year (when everyone will be using a version of PHP that's cutting edge right now).  However, I can't find a basis in the FAQ for this opinion; am I wrong?

Comment: Perhaps leave it open just long enough for a few people to give the user an answer, then close it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say that these sort of questions are too localised, and are already covered in the close reasons:

> This question is unlikely to ever help any future visitors; it is only relevant to a small geographic area, **a specific moment in time**, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

I've bolded the bit that applies in this case.

Comment: +1 I hadn't thought about localization as applying to time - I only thought of it in regional terms.